# Como recuperar a classe de uma div ao clicar nela?

Tags: javascript, html, div

Gero várias `divs` ao decorrer do tempo com um código *JavaScript*, gostaria de recuperar a classe dessas divs ao clicar nelas. Ou recuperar algum outro parâmetro para usar numa comparação.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar o `this.className`, ou `this.classList` veja o exemplo abaixo.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".btn").forEach(function(elem,idx){
 elem.onclick = click
 })
 
 function click(){
    /// neste contexto `this` é o elemento que foi clicado
    console.log( this.className );
    
    /// voce ainda pode utilizar o classList
    ///  que contem metodos como:
    ///  contains()
    ///  add()
    ///  remove()
    
    /// verificando se na lista de classes do elemento clicado contem a classe 'btn-1'
    console.log( "contains btn-1" , this.classList.contains('btn-1') );
   /// foreach na lista de classes
   this.classList.forEach(function(cls,idx){
       console.log('foreach', idx, cls);
   })

}
```

```html
<div class='btn btn-1'>btn 1</div>
<div class='btn btn-2'>btn 2</div>
<div class='btn btn-3'>btn 3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Trouxe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17060971/get-class-name-from-element-with-onclick) um pequeno exemplo para recuperar o atributo `className` do objeto clicado.

```js
function recuperarClasse(obj) {
        alert(obj.className);
}
```

```html
<span class="minhaClasse" onclick="recuperarClasse(this)">Clique aqui!</span>
```

Ao clicar em cima do `span` "Clique aqui!", será exibido um alerta com a classe do `object`.